# data-toggle="collapse" on link that use js scroll, not working

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

I am using fixed navbar of bootstrap which show a button on small screen, and expand / collaps navbar by clicking on button. Every thing work find.
since my links scroll to a target in the same page, I want the navbar to get collaps once a link in navbar clicked.

I tried to add toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
but it did not collapse the navbar, but when I try the same on p tag, inside the navbar div it works.

My understanding is that when the link in list item click it pass the control to JS to scroll to target and do not collapse.

can anyone help how to make the navbar collapse automatically once the link is clicked.

my code are as follows

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo of . . . " style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 0px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">X </p>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right bg-clr-blue">
          <li class="active" ><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x fa-fw nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x nav-icon"  aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-cog  fa-2x fa-fw nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o  fa-2x fa-fw nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Achievement </a></li>
          <li><a href="#publications"><i class="fa fa-book fa-2x fa-fw nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Publications</a></li>
          <li><a href="#album"><i class="fa fa-object-group fa-2x nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Albums</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Us</a></li>
```

and the JS function that control smooth scrolling is

```
$(function() {
            $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);

                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
                    }, 1000);
                return false;
                }
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Share your snippet code please

Comment: just added the function that control the scrolling when clicked on link.

Comment: should I delete this question now?

Comment: No, Is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I realized the problem could be due to JS scrolling function that scroll the screen to the required section.

I just remove the "return false" from the last line of JS function that control the scrolling to target section and now it is working fine, although the nave bar collapsing not seem smooth animated, may be need to make animation slow.